# Consideration about Bernoulli Theorem

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, aerodynamics

I was considerating the Bernoulli Statement about the fact that in a Stationary and Inviscid Flow an increase in the speed of a fluid particle correspond to a decrease in its static pressure. I'm ignoring the contribute of the gravity.

So i can imagine a little cube of gas molecules that feel a difference of pressure around her, from left to right, and increase its speed because a force is acting (derived from the difference of pressure between the two side of the particle). Bernoulli says that, in these condition, the particle will increase speed and decrease in static pressure.

But what would happen if I close some gas molecules into a box of steel, and then I accelerate these box whit my hand? The gas will increase velocity (of course), but will even decrease in pressure? In other words, does the static pressure inside my car decrease when i'm driving faster?

If you think at the box as a fluid particle, i cannot see the difference with the Bernoulli model problem. In both cases, the particle is feeling a force acting on her, in the first case due to pressure differences between the left side and the right side, in the second case due the action of my hand.

Comment: By accelerating the box you will add energy to it and its contents, breaking one of the boundary conditions of Bernoulli's theorem.

Comment: I know, but what I'm doing is just applying a Force to the box. The particle in a flow accelerate for the same reason (in this case the force derive from the pressure around the particle). So where is the difference?

Comment: The difference is where the force comes from. Regular acceleration is caused by a pressure gradient and acceleration uses up this pressure. This acceleration has a source **internal** to the flow. When pushing the box, the force is **external**.

Comment: I'm not sure that I'm understanding. I'm thinking about the fluid particle as a system, and the pressure of the fluid around it exert a force that is external to the system. So I don't see a difference between the action of my hand or the action of the pressure gradient.

Comment: Is your hand also used up in the process of acceleration?

Comment: My hand is an external force as the pressure around the particle...

Comment: Are you trolling? Why would pressure be external???